# Windows 10 idle log off override streaming (youtube/ netflix)

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to override cpu activity as the trigger for idle sleep / logoff.

I know at work you would solve this with group policy, but I'm unclear on how to best solve this at home, the issuse I have is my kids use PCs and will stream video and walk away and the computer will continue to burn kwh and eat into my ISPs data cap.

I've tried several configurations in the power profiles for inactivity, but I think because the CPU is active it never goes idle and I find it hours later and have to manually shut it down.

I'd like to trigger off kb / mouse inactivity if possible and just trigger sleep, even if chrome is open and youtube is on autoplay etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I added an override rule to PowerCfg and this seems to work and sleep the computer at the designated time, even if something is streaming.

```
PowerCfg /REQUESTOVERRIDE PROCESS Chrome.exe DISPLAY DRIVER EXECUTION
```

Thanks to @davidbaumann for pointing me in this direction

Comment: Set one as solution please.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process is preventing your Display to sleep:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

This was the output while running Firefox watching a YouTube stream.

So now you can disable this using a group policy, which does not require a domain:

- Open Local Group Policy Editor (GPedit.msc).
- Go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Power Management -> Sleep Settings.
- Set the following two settings to Disabled:

  - Allow Applications to Prevent Automatic Sleep (On Battery)
  - Allow Applications to Prevent Automatic Sleep (Plugged In)

Comment: I set it up on his machine and started up youtube on autoplay we'll see what happens, should have a 30 min sleep unattended sleep timeout already.

Comment: No change, I also tried setting the /requestsoverride on chrome for display, driver and exectuion, no change.

Comment: turns out it was the override I just didn't wait long enough, still wouldn't have bothered to look here if you didn't point me to powercfg / requests